# fullcalendar Can't disable resizing and enable draggable

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalender and I am not able to disable resizing and enable draggable

My event is

```
[{
 "title":"Test2",
 "start":"2019-09-28T11:00:00",
 "end":"2019-09-28T13:00:00",
 "backgroundColor":"red",
 "textColor":"white",
 "constraint":"businessHours",
 "eventDurationEditable":false,
 "eventStartEditable":true
 }]
```

But not draggable, when I see on website If I change to:

```
editable: true,
eventDurationEditable:false
```

event draggable and resizible

Comment: Actually there's slightly more to it than that. Assuming you're using version 4 then you need to need to load the "interaction" plugin. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/editable. If you still have a problem after that then please create us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can fully understand the situation. Thanks

Comment: I'm use all. It works. But I need only draggable and not resizible.

Comment: You seem to be setting global options in an event context. When you set these options for each event then the option names are different (without the "event" prefix) - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing. If you set them as whole-calendar options then your naming would be correct. Therefore, in your event data try `"editable": true, "durationEditable": false` instead

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be setting global options in an event context. When you set these options for each event then the option names are different (without the "event" prefix) - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing.

If you set them as whole-calendar options then your naming would be correct.

Therefore, in your event data use

```
"editable": true, 
"durationEditable": false
```

instead

Comment: This works great, I was making the same mistake, setting global options on my events (e.g. 'eventDurationEditable' instead of 'durationEditable'.